# Достава Одесою чи привіз в межах Одеси

Tags: переклад, from-russian, прийменники

Треба перекласти вираз "доставка по Одессе". Словники пропонують "довіз" і "достава". Питання в місці - якщо за адресою, то чи доречно сказати "Достава Одесою"? Мандрувати горами, йти шляхом - природньо, а якщо сенс в обмеженому просторі?

Answer (score 1):

Цілком можливе використання прийменника **по** у сполученні **Достава по Одесі**, адже словник фіксує значення словосполуки "прийменник+місцевий відмінок іменника" таке:

> 2. з місц. в. Уживається при вказуванні на місце, простір, у межах якого відбувається дія, рух або хто-, що-небудь перебуває,
>      розташовується, розміщується.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/po)